# three layer of data, Parent-Child-Grandchild

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate issue where I have three layer of data, Parent-Child-Grandchild, Parent to Child one to many and child to grand child one to many. I am unable to save data when I say parent save (hibernate session save method), I use cascade.ALL. I am able to save two layer, parent to child one to many. What I need to do  in this case. I have one parent record which has two child records and each child record has three grand child record. Please help.

Comment: Show us the code for the hibernate entities. In both the parent and child entities do you have the cascade set correctly?

Comment: Parent:@Entity
@Table(name = "enroll_req_cont")

public class EnrollmentRequestContainer implements Serializable {

Comment: Parent:@Entity
@Table(name = "enroll_req_cont")

public class A implements Serializable {
... other fields then

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.REMOVE })
 @JoinColumn(name = "container_id")
    private List<B> enrollmentRequest = new ArrayList<B>();


Then the B:

@Entity
@Table(name = "enroll_request")

public class B implements Serializable {

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.REMOVE })
 @JoinColumn(name = "enrollment_id")
 private List<C> progArgList = new ArrayList<C>();

Comment: using all javax.persistence imports: import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;

Comment: instead of adding comments, please edit the question with formatted code snippets

Answer (score -1):

You need a Self Reference One-to-Many relationship. It does not matter how many levels you need.

Here is a good tutorial which can guide you:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/

Comment: but my situation is not like given in the example, mine is simpler, parent to child (onetomany) child to grand child (onetomany). I am not trying to reference employee and manager in the same entity. It's three separate entities. Only issue is Hibernate does not auto assign the generated key at the grand child level.

Comment: got it fixed, the table where the key is a foreign key, it should not be set as not null from the ddl, it should be null then Hibernate will assign the foreign key correctly.